# Rounding error in double vs string.Format the same number

Tags: c#, optimization, c#-4.0

I have a double which has actual value (as seen from the debugger) `val = 1.5530000000000002`

however if I print it like `string.Format("{0}", val)` I get "1.553" which is realistic value I am looking for.

the `1.5530000000000002` comes from some socket API and I cant change that. But I need 1.553..

what shall I do?

Please note I receive thousands of these per sec. I **can't afford** tinkering with the `Math` class or **converting them forth and back**. any consolations?

Comment: How do you receive these? Are they strings, 8-byte floating point values, or something else?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why does it need to be _exactly_ 1.553?  Usually the imprecision is negligible, as long as you're not doing a lot of repeated computations where the errors can accumulate.

Comment: FYI, in double precision, 1.553 == 1.55299999999999993605115378159.  The next available number (I believe) is 1.553000000000009928058375408.  So, to be fair, the number you're receiving actually isn't 1.553 (even within double precision), but it's pretty close.

Comment: @all.. The number is 1.553 because I know it is. I need it because I have Dictionary with Key on it. The actual question was - why Format makes it right?

Comment: @gabe if i had strings from socket i wont be asking.

Comment: Your question was phrased in such a way that nobody could reasonably be expected to help you. See my revision for a way to ask the question in a way that would enable us to provide a useful answer.

Comment: @Bobb, regarding the behavior of Format, that's because the default displayed precision of Format is 15 digits.  So it's actually displaying a value that is slightly less precise than the underlying storage supports; it does this because we often use doubles to represent decimal values of lower precision and displaying the actual value to its true precision reveals an implementation detail that's usually not relevant.  On a side note, it's generally a bad idea to use a double as a key, for exactly this reason; it sounds like you found a suitable granularity for your purposes, however.

Comment: Thank you Dan. Why dont you answer? I will mark it as the answer. Because this is what I asked (regardless the decimals vs double wrestling here)

Comment: @ downvoter. so whats the deal with the downvotes without comments? did I ask obivous question? did you know the answer by the way or you just enjoy ruining other people reputation? judging anonymously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to upscale them to ints. I can do it because I know how many significant digits are in the number.

```
int real = (int)(dbl * multiplier);
```

I am sure decimals will be slower simply because I dont have x128 CPU and memory bus. Using Math is out questions ever.

*sorry for the blur with casting to float earlier.*

**EDIT** OK. So I got that SO now is not free anymore. Each question need now attention which is costly in time... Here is the code which answers why I will not use Decimals and Math.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Start();
        Console.ReadLine();                
    }

    static int TESTS = 10;
    static int LOOPS = 50000;

    static double d1 = 1.5530000000000002;
    static double d2 = 1.5531;

    static double dResult;
    static int iResult;
    static decimal cResult;

    static void Start()
    {
        // actual test
        for (int x = 0; x < TESTS; x++)
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

            long tick1, tick2, tick3;
            sw.Start();
            for (int j = 0; j < LOOPS; j++)
            {
                dResult = Math.Round(d1 / 2.0, 4);
                dResult = Math.Round(d2 / 2.0, 4);
            }
            sw.Stop();

            tick1 = sw.ElapsedTicks;

            sw.Restart();
            for (int j = 0; j < LOOPS; j++)
            {
                iResult = (int)(d1 / 2.0 * 10000.0);
                iResult = (int)(d2 / 2.0 * 10000.0);
            }
            sw.Stop();

            tick2 = sw.ElapsedTicks;

            sw.Restart();
            for (int j = 0; j < LOOPS; j++)
            {
                cResult = decimal.Round((decimal)d1, 4);
                cResult = decimal.Round((decimal)d2, 4);
            }
            sw.Stop();

            tick3 = sw.ElapsedTicks;

            Console.WriteLine("Math {0} Int {1} Decimal {2}", tick1, tick2, tick3);
        }
    }
}
```

first part - is Math, second is what I am intended to use (conversion to int), and the third is Decimals.

**The results on my i7 as follows - 12K ticks, 700 ticks, 35K ticks respectively.**

Comment: You are aware that you can't express 1.553 as a float either, right? It's actually something like 1.55299997.

Comment: @Gabe His point is that it's fastest to use `int` scaled by 10000.  @Bobb: You *repeatedly* state that you CANNOT use math, and then you answer by using multiplication?  I regret entering this discussion.

Comment: @Scott: When I wrote my comment, Bobb's answer was that he could just convert to a `float`. Note that he said that he cannot use `Math` (the BCL class); presumably math (arithmetic) is OK.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `double` is a floating-point value, and it might be IMPOSSIBLE for it to hold exactly `1.5530000000000000`.  The `decimal` type is better for holding an exact value like this.

If you cannot change `double` to `decimal` in the socket API, then you have no choice but to use math to fix this issue.  In that case, you will need to convert the `double` to a `decimal`, then perform the math to  adjust for the accuracy you desire.

Here's how you can easily do that:

```
double value = 1.5530000000000002;
decimal rounded = decimal.Round((decimal)value, 3);
```

Comment: This is the proper answer. If you use double you can't really count on its precision. If you want precision use decimal.

Answer (score 0):

The `Math` class is more than capable of doing thousands of those per second. So all you need to do is `Math.Floor(val, 3)` or `Math.Round(val, 3)`.

Comment: @Bobb: Try measuring using sockets. There is no way you receive information faster than you can round something down.

Comment: of course you can receive faster. data is flowing non stop. delays in sockets irrelevant - although data was sent 200ms ago it still is flowing in abundance. plus there is not just one socket... so please dont argue. the question was - how to NOT use Math. thanks

Comment: @Bobb: Okay, well, if you want my benchmarks, here they are. 10,000 iterations. `Math.Round` takes 1 millisecond, `CSng` takes 1 millisecond, and doing nothing at all takes 0.8 milliseconds, at least on my computer. And you're not doing nothing.

Comment: Okay. I dont know hot to get to the chat from this website - let me know I will give you the code. I tested 50K Math.Round vs multiplying and casting to int.... Math takes 12K ticks on average, int takes 700 ticks which is 1700% faster. Wanna bet?

Comment: see code in my answer here. feel free to run it and let me know how it goes on your PC.

Comment: @Bobb: Maybe your computer is *diffrent*. Who knows. Please, let's drop this. You've got your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, then, you need to be using a decimal data type, not double. Decimal can store exact values, with the scope of it's precision; double cannot, hence the observed behaviour.

Comment: fundamentally Steve I need a big pension account and 360 days holiday on Cuba... but yeah. need to deal with pesky doubles.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use Double? If not you could use `Decimal.Round(val, 3)`, for example.

Comment: @Bobb: Based on the questions I have seen on this site, I never make any assumptions about what someone knows or doesn't know. Even if you knew it, you might have been so focused on solving it one way that you forgot about alternate approaches. I have done this many, many times in my career and sometimes it takes someone mentioning something that might otherwise seem obvious to get me back on path. I was just trying to be helpful. Thank you.